# Variable assignment results in 'is not recognized as an internal or external command'

Tags: powershell, command-line, windows-8.1

I found a little script in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn247549.aspx) that would really help me:

```
$Tpm = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Tpm -namespace "root\CIMv2\Security\MicrosoftTpm"
$ConfirmationStatus = $Tpm.GetPhysicalPresenceConfirmationStatus(22).ConfirmationStatus
if($ConfirmationStatus -ne 4) {$Tpm.SetPhysicalPresenceRequest(18)}
```

However, when I run it (in both cmd and PowerShell) I get

> '$Tpm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

I don't know much about windows shell programming, and I was hoping someone might poing the errors here.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are running this in PowerShell and not Command Prompt?

Comment: Can you just give  the result of the following command when you run it on a PowerShell elevated prompt : `Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Tpm -namespace "root\CIMv2\Security\MicrosoftTpm"`. "GetPhysicalPresenceConfirmationStatus" exists begining window 8 or W2K12.

Comment: How exactly are you running it? It must be saved as a `.ps1` file, not `.bat` or `.cmd`.

Comment: `is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` is generally what a CMD prompt would say. Powershell errors look completely different.

Comment: I had to run it as Admin... Silly!